# How to give shades to this cuboid

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am beginner in LaTeX. I have seen many tikz pakages here but I get confuse. But for the same shap different people use different codes. I feel difficult to understand. That's why my LaTeX skills are not improving quickly. I have made a cuboid with simple codes. But I am stuck how to give shades. I saw some answers on stack exchange but I didn't understand yet since all feel me difficult. Here is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[draw=black,fill=gray!20!white] (0,0,0)--(1.5,0,0)node[below]{$\delta x$}-- (3,0,0)--(3,2,0)--(0,2,0)-- cycle;
\draw[draw=black,fill=gray!20!white] (3,0,0)--(3,0,-1)node[above=2pt]{$h$}--(3,0,-2)--(3,1,-2)node[right]{$\delta y$}--(3,2,-2) --(3,2,0)--cycle;
\draw[draw=black,fill=gray!20!white] (0,2,0)--(3,2,0)--(3,2,-2)--(0,2,-2)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And the output is[image]

How can I shade it? So that it looks like real cuboid (shade in gray colour).
Thank you.

Comment: I am unsure how you would expect a “real cuboid” to look like. Wouldn’t the three sides just have different shades of gray? You can achieve this by just changing the value in `gray!20!white` to something else such as `gray!10!white` for the respective area.

Answer (score 2):

I could get shading with the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{cuboid}{100bp}{
    color(0bp)=(gray!0);
    color(25bp)=(gray!25);
    color(50bp)=(gray!50);
    color(75bp)=(gray!75);
    color(100bp)=(gray!100)
}
\draw[draw=black,shading=cuboid] (0,0,0)--(1.5,0,0)node[below]{$\delta x$}-- (3,0,0)--(3,2,0)--(0,2,0)-- cycle;
\draw[draw=black,shading=cuboid] (3,0,0)--(3,0,-1)node[above=2pt]{$h$}--(3,0,-2)--(3,1,-2)node[right]{$\delta y$}--(3,2,-2) --(3,2,0)--cycle;
\draw[draw=black,shading=cuboid] (0,2,0)--(3,2,0)--(3,2,-2)--(0,2,-2)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This generates the output:

[image: Output shaded]

Answer (score 1):

Ti*k*Z is not a 3D rendering software, but you can just change the colors of the different areas to make them darker. Typically, light comes from the upper left corner, so the front and the right side of the cuboid should be darker. You could also use a radial gradient and some clipping tricks to add a subtle reflection effect to the upper side:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[black, fill=gray!45] 
        (0,0,0) -- (1.5,0,0) node[below] {$\delta x$} -- 
        (3,0,0) -- (3,2,0) -- (0,2,0) -- cycle;
    \draw[black, fill=gray!65] 
        (3,0,0) -- (3,0,-1) node[above=2pt]{$h$} -- 
        (3,0,-2) -- (3,1,-2) node[right]{$\delta y$} --
        (3,2,-2) -- (3,2,0) -- cycle;
    \begin{scope}
        \path[clip, save path=\surface] 
            (0,2,0) -- (3,2,0) -- (3,2,-2) -- (0,2,-2) -- cycle;
        \fill[inner color=white, outer color=gray!25] 
            (-2,2) rectangle (4,4);
    \end{scope}
    \draw[black] [use path=\surface];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]